# Find the span of $v_1, v_2, ..., v_k, w$ when $x_1 \cdot v_1 + x_2 \cdot v_2 + ... + x_k \cdot v_k = w$ has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

I have been given the following question

> Given $v_1, v_2, ... v_k, u, w$ vectors in a liner space $V$, and given that $v_1 \cdot x_1 + v_2 \cdot x_2 + ... + v_k \cdot x_k = u$ has a single solution where as $v_1 \cdot x_1 + v_2 \cdot x_2 + ... + v_k \cdot x_k = w$ has no solutions. What is the dimension of $sp\{v_1...v_k,w\}$

It is obvious to me that I need to prove that $v_1,...,v_k$ in liner independent and that because the second equation does not have any solutions then $v_1,...,v_k$, $w$ must be liner independent as well, and from that I need to prove that $dim(sp\{v_1,...,v_k,w\}) = k + 1$.

But I cant figure out how can I prove the last part and I don't know how to prove that $v_1,...,v_k$ in liner independent. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$ \sum_{m=1}^k x_m \mathbf{v}_m = \mathbf{u} $$
has **only one** solution. This would imply the set of vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k\}$ are linearly independent. Otherwise one can write one vector $ \mathbf{v}_i $ as linear combination of other vectors and there will be more than one solution (you may try to write out the other solutions explicitly to verify the above argument).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try to prove that if the vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k\}$ are linearly dependent then $$\sum_{m=1}^k x_m \mathbf{v}_m = \mathbf{u}$$ has either no solution or more than one solutions for every $\mathbf{u}$ in $\Bbb V$. The above is just the contrapositive argument.

Answer (score 0):

The First Equation has only one solution and the second Equation have no solution.This means that $\mu \in span\left\{v_{1},\cdots,v_{m} \right\}$ and $ \omega\notin span\left\{v_{1},\cdots,v_{m} \right\}$.This implies that dim($span\left\{v_{1},\cdots,v_{m} \right\}$)=m+1.This proves the conclusion.